# Understanding natural isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am still trying to understand the concept of a natural or canonical isomorphism and I actually think I understand the idea but maybe somebody could help me in the following:

Let $R$, $A$ be rings (commutative with unit) and $S\subset R$ a multiplicatively closed subset, $\tau_A:R\rightarrow A$ a ring homomorphism satisfying $\tau_A(S)\subset A^*$ and $f:A\rightarrow R_S$ an isomorphism. Let $\tau_S:R\rightarrow R_S$ be the ring homomorphism associated to $R_S$.

Is it true in this situation that the natural morphism $\phi:R_S\rightarrow A$ (satisfying $\phi\circ\tau_S=\tau_A$) actually is an isomorphism? As $f$ can be an arbitrary, unnatural isomorphism (meaning $\tau_A\neq f^{-1}\circ \tau_S$) it feels like it's not true but then again I can't find a counterexample.

So maybe someone can give a hint, thanks already!

Comment: It's rather because $\tau_A$ can be arbitrary that $\phi$ need not be an isomorphism. For instance let $S=\{1\}$, $A=R$ and $\tau_A$ a not-iso endomorphism

Comment: just as a small note, you may not want to call the morphism $\phi$ "natural" in this context. It is more that $\phi$ is induced by a universal property. Calling things "natural isomorphism" (like the isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its double dual) often hints that there is some natural transformation of functors going on (even if that isn't explicit what the functors are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example 
$$R=k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots], A=k(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, y)$$
where $k$ is a field and $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, y $ are indeterminates, $S=R\setminus\{0\}$ and $\tau_A$ is the obvious inclusion (every $x_i$ is sent to $x_i$).
Then $\tau_S$ is the inclusion of $R$ into its fraction field, which is $R_S=k(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$, and $\phi$ is the obvious inclusion of this field to $A$ (again, $x_i$ goes to $x_i$). In particular, $\phi$ is not an isomorphism, because $y$ is not in the image.

However, there is an isomorphism $f:R_S \rightarrow A$: Just send $x_1$ to $y$ and each $x_i$ to $x_{i-1}, \;\;i\geq 2$.

**Remark:** In case you don't believe in non-Noetherian rings, you can obtain a Noetherian example of the same type from this by replacing $R$ by $R$ localized at, say, $S'=k[x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots]\setminus \{0\}$, so that $R_{S'}=K[x_1]$ for a field $K=k(x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots)$.